# Why Find Nearby App is not available in App Exchange?

Tags: appexchange, app

I am looking for free version of "Find Nearby App" for my client. One month back I have installed this app in Client Sandbox. Now I am trying to install this in Production system I just wondering this app is not available in App Exchange. why is this app not available now? any ideas. please let me know if they have changed the name of the app.

Comment: Im also face the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

The terms and conditions of the google maps api, which Find Nearby relies on, where changed as of February 1st.  All users now need a google apps for business license to use this app, which starts from $10,000 per year. Without this, the map will be replaced with a link to purchase a license.

http://pages.arrowpointe.com/2014-01-30FindNearbyAlternative_GoogleMapsAPIAlertfromSalesforce.html?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRonuqvOZKXonjHpfsX56%2BwoXKW1lMI%2F0ER3fOvrPUfGjI4ATcRgI%2BSLDwEYGJlv6SgFS7HHMbJr07gOWxM%3D

The key message is:

> Note: The "Find Nearby - Accounts, Contacts, Leads" AppExchange
>   package does not have a commercial agreement with Google. You will
>   need to obtain a  Google Maps API for Business license to continue
>   using this package.

Given that Salesforce doesn't provide a license with this application, I'd imagine they have decided to pull the application.  You might want to take a look at the Geopointe application (I have no affiliation, I just think its a good product) as this handles the licensing side of things for you:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016ZHeEAM

Comment: Thank you for your response Mr.Bob. I will speak to my client regarding this.